# Getting Identity Resources - Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am new to Identity Server 4, and I am struggling to obtain the users `identities`.  At the moment, I am displaying the `Claims` via an API that Identity Server is protecting as so:

```
namespace API01.Controllers
{
    [Route("identity")]
    [Authorize]
    public class IdentityController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET identity
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {          
            return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that `email` resource is just showing up as the value `email` when I decode the `jwt`.

```
"scope": [
    "email",
    "openid",
    "api1"
  ],
```

I have been experimenting with `User.Identities` but so far I cannot get the information I need from my `AllowedScopes {"email", "openid", "api1"}`.

Basically, I want to obtain the value which in my case is `test@test.com`.  I am not worried about returning a `JsonResult`, just a string would suffice for now, if its going to be difficult.

Comment: Please confirm whether you are mapping claims with user (i.e AspNetuserClaims table) when you are adding new user.

Comment: Yes I am, but there is something I noticed just now...  I am mapping `claims` to `users` but I am not using `Claims = new [] { new "claim 1", new "claim 2", ... }`, mine is `Claims = { new "claim 1", new "claim 2", … }`.  I'm not sure if this matters.  Will test when I have some time as I am just reading up on Quickstart 3 from the docs.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to include the email claim in your id token , you can add the `IdentityResources.Email()` in `IdentityResource` of IDS4 :

```
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
{
    return new List<IdentityResource>
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        new IdentityResources.Email()
    };
}
```

Also set `AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken` to `true` in client config :

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "mvc",
    ClientName = "MVC Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

    ....

    ....
    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "api1",
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
    },
    AllowOfflineAccess = true
},
```

You can start from [Identity Server4 code samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts) .

If you want to find the `scopes` in jwt token , id token won't include the `scopes` claim , but access token includes since api should validate that .

Comment: Appreciate the answer, I have tried the above and I am still not able to access the actual value of the email from the token or the action method's `jsonResult`.  I have started making my way through the quickstarts, I am on number 2 `GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword` which might be an issue since I noticed you have `GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials`.  So just to clarify, I am receiving an ID Token or an Access Token?  As I've read the latter doesn't carry such information?

Comment: use hybrid flow or resource owner flow is not the problem . If you acquire API access, then you will get id token and also access token . ID token claim will map to user principle which you could retire by  User.Claims

Answer (score 1):

Scope array indicates what is allowed to access.
You probably want to see email claim in the token.

For that you need to implement `IProfilrService` and add all the claims from `Subject` to `IssuedClaims`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not bothered about it being shown in the Token, just more interested in obtaining it in the `Get()` method of my API and doing something with it.

Comment: Yeah, but what creates User with all its claims? Is it middleware API? From the token? Does it contain the claims you need ;-)

Comment: I have a Token server (web api), a web api with middleware, and a console app as the client.  Have you an example as I'm not quite sure what is required here.  Thanks,

Comment: Is token server Identity Server 4? https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1596

Comment: Yes it is Identity Server 4

Comment: Get the raw token with postman and check [here](https://jwt.io/) whether it contains the claims you need. I bet it doesn’t because by default IS4 doesn’t put them into token.

Comment: It definitely doesn't show the `scoped` values when looking at the raw token via `jwt.io`